# Can an MP3 contain 5.1 or 7.1 Surround Sound Audio?

Tags: mp3

I know that the MP3 file format essentially supports mono and stereo audio with a number of sample rates and bit rates, but can it contain true surround sound audio? Is there a way to pack more than 2 channels into an MP3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

You could use [MP3 surround](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3_Surround) (an extension of MP3, not part of the MP3 specification) if you really want to. It is backwards-compatible with MP3 (which, I assume, means that most MP3 players will simply play it back as a stereo MP3). You'll probably have to pay for an encoder or decoder, though.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this with MPEG-1 layer 3.  You would need to use MPEG-2 part 3.

For real-world encoding, you'll probably want to use an AC3 or AAC 5.1 encoder.  Audacity with the ffmpeg plugin can do this for you if you're just concerned about encoding audio.